# Create Multiple Queues at Once

Tags: c++, queue

Is there a way i can create multiple queues at once?

For example my program will ask. How many queues the user wants, if he submits 3 then it will create 3 queues that look like this.

```
queue<int> queue1;

queue<int> queue2;

queue<int> queue3;
```

Do i create a for loop to do this? Or is there another way to do so?

```
for (int i = 0; i<userInput; i++)
{
   queue<int> queue[i];
}
```

Would the above work?
Basically ask the user how many queues they want created, and it will create them based on his input.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<queue<int>> queues(n);
```